# Error en JavaScript: Uncaught TypeError:

Tags: javascript, html, json, array

Alguien me puede ayudar con un error que me aparece y no sé que significa ni cómo solucionarlo, se lo agradecería mucho. Este es el error que me aparece:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read private member #productos from an
> object whose class did not declare it

Y esta es la línea de código con la que me sale el error:

```
this.#productos.push(nuevoProducto);
```

Y el `nuevoProducto` es un elemento que intento agregar a un array en un JSON.

Comment: ¿Esta declarado `#productos` de antemano? ¿Puedes enseñarnos la clase?

Comment: Si está declarado de antemano, desde el principio

export default class Productos {
    #productos;
    #formEdicion;

    constructor() {
        this.#productos = []
    }

Comment: Así como está no debería tirar ese error, debería tirar otro... intenta quitar el `#`

Comment: Como dice @ArtEze lo mas sencillo es que hagas la variable publica, pero según el error, estas llamando a la variable desde fuera de la clase y en este caso si ha de ser publica, eso o exponer un método publico que modifique la variable privada.

Comment: @Principianteentodo Podrías [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/379217/edit) agregando el código (mediante ctrl+k) en vez de dejarlo en los comentarios. De esa manera quedaría más legible.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos, ahora me sale otro error al quitar el #.... Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Creo que seria mas rapido que nos mostrases el codigo donde se encuentra el push. Porque parece que estas usando `this` en donde no deberias.

Comment: Te aseguro que lo pongo donde es, pero igual te muestro: 

guardarAdicion() {
        let nuevoProducto = {
            id: document.querySelector('#productos-adicion #identificador').value,
            referencia: document.querySelector('#productos-adicion #referencia').value,
            imagen: document.querySelectorAll('#productos-adicion #txtImagen').value
        }

        console.log(nuevoProducto);
        this.productos.push(nuevoProducto);
    }

Answer (score 1):

La manera en que se está declarando la clase, con esos `#`, me da la sospecha que debería tirar error. Es mejor no usar el `#` al declarar propiedad. Lo que sí puede hacerse es usar el `#` en el `querySelector`, es decir, es una ruta CSS finalmente.

```
export default class Productos {
    #productos;
    #formEdicion;
```

Me imagino que el proyecto se trata de algo que varía la cantidad de imágenes, y el usuario tiene que cambiar valores.

El problema está aquí:

```
imagen: document.querySelectorAll('#productos-adicion #txtImagen').value
```

Se está intentando devolver el valor de una lista de imágenes, es decir, **no los valores de una lista, sino el valor de una lista**.

Pero además el `querySelectorAll` no devuelve un array, en vez de eso devuelve una colección, que para procesarla hay que convertirla a array.

Para lograr esto, se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
var valores = [...document.querySelectorAll('#txtImagen')].map(x=>{
    return x.value
})
```

Para un solo `txtImagen` se está usando el atributo HTML `id`, y en el `querySelector` se accede con `#`, pero como hay más de uno, hay que usar el atributo HTML `class` y en el `querySelector` usar un `.`.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.txtImagen')]
```

Para el botón de **Guardar Adición**, al hacer `click`, llamo a una función anónima que llama al método `guardarAdicion`, y en vez de un `onclick` en el HTML, hago un `addEventListener` en JavaScript.

```
document.querySelector("#productos-adicion #guardarAdicion")
.addEventListener("click",()=>window.productos.guardarAdicion())
```

Si llamo normalmente al método, no funciona, para eso necesito una función anónima. Es decir, lo siguiente trae problemas.

```
.addEventListener("click",window.productos.guardarAdicion)
```

En cambio, al usar la función anónima `()=>`, anda bien:

```
.addEventListener("click",()=>window.productos.guardarAdicion())
```

Código completo:

```js
class Productos {
  constructor() {
    this.productos = []
  }
  guardarAdicion() {
    let nuevoProducto = {}
    var valores = [["id","identificador"],
    ["referencia","referencia"],
    ["imágenes","txtImagen"]].map(function(x){
      nuevoProducto[x[0]] = [
        ...document.querySelectorAll(
          `#productos-adicion .${x[1]}`
        )
      ].map(x=>x.value)
      if(nuevoProducto[x[0]].length<2){
        nuevoProducto[x[0]] = nuevoProducto[x[0]][0]
      }
    })
    var div = document.createElement("div")
    div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(nuevoProducto)
    document.querySelector("#resultado").appendChild(div)
    this.productos.push(nuevoProducto)
  }
}
window.productos = new Productos()

document.querySelector("#productos-adicion #guardarAdicion")
.addEventListener("click",()=>window.productos.guardarAdicion())

document.querySelector("#productos-adicion #cantidadImagenes")
.addEventListener("keyup",function(x){
  var imagenes = document.querySelector("#productos-adicion #imagenes")
  var cantidad = + x.target.value
  var i = 1
  imagenes.innerHTML = ""
  var dentro = [...Array(cantidad)].map(()=>{
    var div = document.createElement("div")
    var input = document.createElement("input")
    input.className = "txtImagen"
    div.innerHTML = `Imagen ${i}: `
    div.appendChild(input)
    imagenes.appendChild(div)
    ++i
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="productos-adicion">
  <div>Cantidad de imágenes: 
    <input id="cantidadImagenes" />
    <button id="guardarAdicion">Guardar Adición</button>
  </div>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>Identificador: <input class="identificador"/></div>
        <div>Referencia: <input class="referencia"/></div>
        <div id="imagenes">
          <div>Imagen 1: <input class="txtImagen"/></div>
          <div>Imagen 2: <input class="txtImagen"/></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="resultado"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```